# Highlight positions of the marks in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am practising `'[` and `']`, and I cannot see the difference.

How can you highlight the positions of the marks?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [showmarks](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=152) plugin for VIM.  It does just that.

Answer (score 16):

[vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) worked well for showing marks.

[showmarks](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=152) didn't work for me.  It also hasn't been updated in nearly a decade.

Answer (score 5):

I find several marks related plugins on GitHub, which shows marks on the signcolumn and provide commands to manage your marks:

- [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature)
- [vim-markology](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-markology)
- [vim-markbar](https://github.com/Yilin-Yang/vim-markbar)

Currently, I am using vim-signature and it works great. You may try these plugins and choose what suits you best.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that the previously changed or yanked text was all on one line. If you use ' with a mark it just takes you to the line, not to the exact character. Use ` instead to get the exact character.

One way to temporarily highlight the region would be to type this:

```
`[v`]
```

This will jump to the start change/yank mark, start a visual block and then jump to the end change/yank mark.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can "blink" the matching delimiter ([{}]) ... using the **%** (percent sign) command in `vi`.

(That's not even unique to `vim` ... it works in other versions of `vi` as well).

The **'[** and **']** (single quote, square brackets) are unique to `vim` as far as I know.  They move to the first non-blank character on the first or last line where most recently modified or "put" any text.  If your most recent change only only affected a single line then the commands would both move to the same place (as you described).

Note that the **'** command (in normal `vi` as well as `vim`) is a movement.  **'*letter*** (single quote followed by any lower case letter) is a command to move to the locate where a mark was most recently set (using the **m** command, of course).  **''** (repeating the single quote command twice) moves to "most recent" cursor location (think of there being a implicit mark there).  That's the most recent location from which you initiated a movement or made a change (**'[** and **']** are ONLY about where you made changes).

For example if I'm on line 100 and I use **n** to search for the next occurrence of my current search pattern, then **''** will get me back to line 100.  From there if I type **''** again then it will toggle me back to whatever the search (**n**) command found.
Personally I never use **'[** and **']** ... I drop a mark using **ma** (or b, or c or whatever) and then make my changes or pastes before or after the mark I've set, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This command will show the marks:

```
:match Error /\%'[\|\%']/
```

Comment: I left a mark by `ma`. I run your command. I do not see the mark. **How does the command work?**

Comment: My command only shows the special marks '[ and '], that is all you asked for in the question.